# Server Architecture for application that needs to have country code top level domain

Tags: database, server, rdbms, web-development-server, database-mirroring

I was working on an web and mobile application which was startup business of Australia. We have our linode server and database in Singapore. We have a separate codebase for web app and mobile app(APIs). The business worked pretty well and now the client wants to expand their service in USA too.

The web app was hosted as `appname.com.au` and now he wants to launch the Application in USA as `appname.com`. And he wants to utilize the same mobile application for both Australia and USA because of not enough funding.

The problem is there will be many additional features/modifications in business logic for USA.

- My main concern is should I continue on single web app or make new app for USA.
- Since, we already have two separate codebases i.e. one for existing web app and another for APIs => mobile app. Maintaining more codebases will be very difficult for us.
- The products that is sold via app should be location aware i.e. as popular products for one state of USA from another or from Australia will obviously vary, features product in home page should vary too.
- The products uploaded to the Australia can be seen by the users of USA but, shouldn't be able to buy and vice-versa.

For this, should we continue to work on the same app or go with the new separate app for USA. Chances are this application will grow hugely in coming days and we need to scale it more thus, we are pretty stuck on what's the right/better thing to do.

Any help will be highly appreciated. If you don't understand it clearly I will let you know via comments. And yeah thanks for your time :)

Comment: What kind of regional/locale requirements do you have? I would not make a different codebase per locale as that won't be scalable in the long term. You need to figure out what specifically changes from region to region and then it becomes easier to roll out a multi physical location / multi AZ infrastructure.

Comment: Since the application that I'm talking about is an e-commerce service. So, the popular product on one USA will definitely vary from the popular products of Australia. And I need to show the popular products as featured products meaning that features products for different region should vary. Also, there might be some changes like this we don't know right away but we need to take care later.

Comment: The same app can still power that with different database instances per region. I would assume the difficult architecture portion here would be all the reporting + ledger data (i.e. completed sales) so you can reconcile all of that within the scope of a single database.